# How to sync different table column names and stored procedures operating on them in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose i have five table a, b, c, d, e and ten stored procedures  doing operations on them. So, now i want to write a stored procedure or something that will check all this tables column names and Stored Procedures column names(taken for operation in this tables) are all sync and if not sync will raise error and stop further doing any operation until it fixed. I can get Column names from Information Schema and Check if tables are sync or not. But for Stored Procedures what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

For comparing table structures, you can use

> information_schema.columns

For doing SP comparison, you can do it through hashes (hashes must be the same for both source/target):

```
declare @spname sysname 
declare @spdefinition varchar(max) 
declare @hashedVal varbinary(4000) 

set @spname = '<Your sp name here>' 

set @spdefinition = (SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(@spname )))     
set @hashedVal = (select HashBytes('SHA1', @spdefinition)) 


select @hashedVal
```

Comment: could you provide me a brief introduction or article or resource from where i can learn more about hashing implementation, as i never implemented hashing in tsql before

Comment: Basically, your procedures will be in sync if they have the same hash values. See it as a "signature" for your procedure. However, I must add that the fact you are forced to do procedure comparison indicates something wrong in the way you work: you should use a proper versioning tool, like subversion, and build your database from that source.

Comment: my case is, i have some tables and some procedures does operations in  that tables, so, i want to check column names of all that tables are sync or not before running any procedure, i resolved sync issue of tables using informationschema.columns, but i couldn't find a way to check in Stored Procedures column names are in sync or not. I don't think it's a versioning issue.